# Is the following a valid question re: The Coulomb force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, rocket-science, propulsion, ions

I'm making up some practice questions for a course on electromagnetism and electric circuits.  I like to make the students think, but I also want to make sure that my questions aren't terribly incorrect.  I was thinking of asking a question that links an interesting application with what they are learning, but I'm not sure if the question is so simplified as to be meaningless.  Here it is:

An ion engine in a spacecraft works by applying an electric field to charged ions.  As the field pushes on those ions, a reactive force is developed on the spacecraft, pushing it forward.

Assume:

- The magnitude of the electric field right at the engine's electrode is $E$ and drops off with the square of the distance from the electrode.
- The mass of the spacecraft is $m$.
- The charge of each ion is $q$.

What is the net change in momentum of the spacecraft that results when 1Kg of propellant is consumed?

My issue here is that I'm 90% sure that the actual way the engine works is much more complex than this.  I'm wondering if the simplifications are OK, or if they make the question so absurd as to be meaningless.  I can always remove the spacecraft part and just have two charged particles pushing each other away, but I like to add in real world applications if I can.

Comment: This problem sounds underspecified. Is the electric field radial or is it always pointing in the same direction? If it were the former, you need to specify the angular distribution. If it were the latter, an inverse square falloff doesn't make sense. Also, it doesn't make sense for a field to _both_ have $1/r^2$ dependence, and be equal to a finite value $E$ at $r = 0$, which is what you appear to be saying. Also, you need the charge of the ions. Also, you need the initial separation of the ions to your electrode. Also, your spacecraft ends up with a net charge; should this be accounted for?

Comment: On behalf of all students everywhere, please be completely sure that your question statements are actually complete. I can think of at least 10 different things you could have meant. This is a recipe for wasting hours and hours of your students' time. Your weak students will see this confusing setup and just plug $E$, $m$, and $q$ into the first formula they see, get an answer, and learn nothing. Your strong students won't get an answer at all because they'll try to make sense of something nonsensical.

Comment: @knzhou: thanks, that's what I was worried about.  I think the question will not be used